# How to retrieve a property from an object within a dictionary in a MongoDB document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Our Mongo data looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542d881b8bc641bbee1f8509"),
        "ExtendedProperties" : {
                "Context" : {
                        "_t" : "LoggingContext",
                        "DeclaringTypeName" : "EndpointConfig"
                }
        }
}
```

In the C# code, the ExtendedProperties are represented as follows:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried every method I can find to be able to query against the value of DeclaringTypeName. Nothing seems to work, as shown in the following code:

```
// This throws an UnsupportedOperationException with the following message:
// Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (LogEntry e) => e.ExtendedProperties.get_Item("DeclaringTypeName").ToString().
query.Add(Query<LogEntry>.EQ(e => ((LoggingContext)e.ExtendedProperties["Context"]), this.DeclaringTypeName ));

// This returns zero matching rows:
query.Add(Query.EQ("ExtendedProperties.Context.DeclaringTypeName", this.DeclaringTypeName));

// This returns zero matching rows:
query.Add(Query.ElemMatch("ExtendedProperties.Context", Query.EQ("DeclaringTypeName", this.DeclaringTypeName)));

// This reports that ExtendedProperties must implement a specific interface and must not return null:
query.Add(Query<LogEntry>.ElemMatch(e => e.ExtendedProperties, qb => Query.EQ("Context.DeclaringTypeName", this.DeclaringTypeName)));
```

For clarity, I have researched every StackOverflow, CodePlex, and Mongo.org thread I can find, and have as yet been unable to resolve this correctly.

Naturally, it's going to be something I'm doing wrong.

Someone please throw me a bone.

Comment: The second one should work fine. I'd go back and see if there is some other problem (perhaps it's not generating the query you think it is).

Comment: What **query.Add(...** does? (What is query?)

Comment: @Disposer: query is a List<IMongoQuery>, so it merely adds it to an existing list of IMongoQuery objects, which are later passed to Query.And().

Comment: I got the result with     var rawQuery = Query.EQ("ExtendedProperties.Context.DeclaringTypeName", "EndpointConfig");
    var query = new List<IMongoQuery>();
    query.Add(rawQuery);
    var rawResult = collection.Find(rawQuery).ToList();

Comment: Are you sure this.DeclaringTypeName is "EndpointConfig"?

Comment: @Disposer, I was, but given that you can make it work and I can't, I'm forced to reexamine the code. At least now I know which method signature/calling convention to use, and that it should work. Now I need to figure out why it's not working. The most likely answer is that what I'm passing doesn't match any value in the database.

Comment: I suggest at first run your query in your mongoshell (or via robomongo), and see what happens. my c# query will turn to db.messages.find({ "ExtendedProperties.Context.DeclaringTypeName" : "EndpointConfig" }). and with c# and mongo I have the expected result

Comment: @Disposer: Please post your comments in an answer. You pointed me in the right direction and solved my problem handily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined the LogEntry class as

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }
}
```

then I inserted the sample document by

```
var log = new LogEntry
{
    ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "Context", new LoggingContext
            {
                DeclaringTypeName = "EndpointConfig"
            }
        }
    }
};

collection.Insert(log);
```

then I performed the query by:

```
var rawQuery = Query.EQ("ExtendedProperties.Context.DeclaringTypeName", "EndpointConfig");
var query = new List<IMongoQuery>();
query.Add(rawQuery);

var rawResult = collection.Find(rawQuery).ToList();
```

the query will send mongo below query

```
db.messages.find({ "ExtendedProperties.Context.DeclaringTypeName" : "EndpointConfig" })
```

And I got the result

Comment: This is the winner. Turns out I was not passing what I thought I was. Thanks!